# How do I write this many_to_many ActiveRecord query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

In this example, I want all `projects` which have `Ruby` AND `HTML` `languages`, which are a many_to_many relationship through `project_languages`.

```
class Project
  has_many :project_languages
  has_many :languages, through: :project_languages
end

class Language 
  has_many :project_languages
  has_many :projects, through: :project_languages
end

class ProjectLanguage
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :language
end
```

What I’m trying, but returns an empty array:

```
Project.joins(:languages).where('languages.name = ? AND languages.name = ?', 'Ruby', 'HTML')
```

This returns the expected result, but I'm thinking there has to be a simpler way:

```
Project.joins(:languages).where(languages: {name: 'Ruby' }) & (Project.joins(:languages).where(languages: {name: 'HTML' }))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems good. But here's an alternate

```
Language.find_by(name: 'Ruby')&.projects & Language.find_by(name: 'HTML')&.projects
```

If you have the language you want in a variable. This can be a simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think to approach it that way.

Comment: `Language.where(name: ['Ruby', 'HTML]).map(&:projects).inject(:&)` .Just found out a more simpler and cool looking. This gives the same result.

Comment: Haha bonus points for "coolness". Thanks again!